# Simple loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

I have this:

```
class Dice
  def roll
    1+ rand(6)
  end
end
```

and this:

```
dices = [Dice.new, Dice.new]
dices.each do |dice|
  puts dice.roll
end
```

I have two dices and I want a loop that calls `roll` until the two dices make 6 and 6. I think that the `until` loop is the one I am looking for, but I don't know where to put it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please avoid using languages other than english when you post code here. People who don't understand italian may have a hard time understanding what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `loop` and `break`:

```
loop do
  dadi = [Dado.new, Dado.new]
  break if dadi.all? { |d| d.lancia == 6 }
end
```

But there's another issue with your code. `lancia` returns another random number every time the method is called:

```
d = Dado.new
d.lancia #=> 4
d.lancia #=> 1
d.lancia #=> 6
```

You cannot inspect the value without changing it. Unless you want a "Schrödinger's dice", it would probably be better to assign an instance variable. Something like:

```
class Dice
  def initialize
    roll
  end

  def roll
    @value = rand(1..6)
  end

  def value
    @value
  end
end

d = Dice.new
d.value #=> 2
d.value #=> 2
d.value #=> 2

d.roll
d.value #=> 4
d.value #=> 4
d.value #=> 4
```